# Running a service in safe mode

Tags: android

I have an android app that has a service that runs in the background.
I need this service to run also f the user is in safe mode.

What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks
Avi

Comment: isn't the safe mode designed in a way that it DISABLES all Third party apps? You are not supposed to build an App which circumvents it. What is if Your App is the cause of trouble, and could not get uninstalled, just because it also crashes the phone in Safe Mode. Question is: WHY do you want to run in safe mode?

Comment: I'm building a parent control app that restricts kids from entering different websites. but in safe mode they can brows wherever they want